# getting this error while submitting in perforce "open for write: /tmp/tmp.27574.29: Read-only file system"

Tags: perforce

I'm facing the following error:

```
[root@ main]# p4 submit -c 758557

Submitting change 758557.

Locking 19 files ...

edit x.sh#88

edit y.Linux#8

edit z.Linux#8

open for write: /tmp/tmp.27775.40: Read-only file system

SSL receive failed.

read: Connection reset by peer: Connection reset by peer

Perforce client error:

    SSL receive failed.

    read: Connection reset by peer: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: This is a problem on your server: the submit command is unable to copy your files to temporary locations on your server. Do you have a server administrator? They can sign on to your server machine and address the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Bryan's comment: your server's /tmp directory is read-only, and that's where the server writes spec files by default, so nothing that involves editing a spec (including submit) will work.

Your server admin should either make /tmp writable to the p4d process (maybe p4d got restarted as the wrong user and lost its access?) or set TMP to a writable directory:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/TMP.html